# InvalidMapKeyType when encoding a HashMap to bson

Tags: rust, bson

I want to encode a `HashMap<u64, usize>` using `bson::to_bson()` in order to store it in MongoDB.

When I ran the code, it panicked and told me that `InvalidMapKeyType(FloatingPoint(....))`. Can't I use this method to encode HashMap in such a type?

Comment: Java often encounters a similar problem. BSON Objects are expecting the "hash key" to be a "string", and that is basically how it's going to be stored. You would do will to stick to that type in your design, or at least cast first before conversion to BSON.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [BSON library disallows all keys that are not strings](https://github.com/zonyitoo/bson-rs/blob/v0.8.0/src/encoder/serde.rs#L369-L375). The [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) states that a document is a sequence of elements, each element must be preceded by a name, and a name can only be a string.

Changing your `HashMap` to use a string as the key should solve the problem.

---

Your question doesn't make any sense to me. You state that you have a `HashMap<u64, usize>` but your error snippet states that it's because of a `FloatingPoint`!

This is why you should always create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) and then provide it when asking a question. I created this sample which does exactly as you stated and I get a different error:

```
extern crate bson; // 0.8.0

use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut thing = HashMap::new();
    thing.insert(0_u64, 1_usize);

    match bson::to_bson(&thing) {
        Ok(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
        Err(e) => println!("Got an error: {:?}, {}", e, e),
    }
}
```

```
Got an error: UnsupportedUnsignedType, BSON does not support unsigned type
```

If I change the `HashMap` to signed numbers, then I get the same class of error:

```
thing.insert(0_i64, 1_isize);
```

```
Got an error: InvalidMapKeyType(I64(0)), Invalid map key type: I64(0)
```

You can't even make a `HashMap` using a `f64` as the key in Rust because it doesn't implement `Hash` or `Eq`, so I have no idea how you got that specific error.